# How to open Dialog from Console App in Avalonia

Tags: dialog, modal-dialog, avaloniaui

I have a Console Application that, at some point, creates a WPF Window, adds VM to Datacontext, and shows window as Dialog. Console runs Further with DialogResult.

I tried the same with Avalonia, but did not get it working. All Examples work with App.axaml an the AppBuilder (That works, if i want an GUI only App)

When I create the Window as in WPF, I got Exceptions that IWindowPlatform can not be located.

Can I do that in Avalonia?

```
int main()
{
    var x = foo();
    // some Initiative code
    var view = MyView();
    var viewModel = MyViewModel(x);
    view.DataContext = viewModel;
    var result = view.ShowDialog();
    if(result==DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        var y = viewModel.Bar;

    }
}
```

Comment: I got it working with some helper injecting window factory

Comment: I suggest adding an answer to your own question if you got it working.  It's perfectly acceptable to do that, but the answer should not be in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helper does the job, but Looks not as intended:

```
using System;
using Avalonia;
using Avalonia.Controls;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;

namespace Foo
{
    public class DialogService
    {
        private readonly Func<Window> windowFactory;

        public DialogService(Func<Window> windowFactory)
        {
            this.windowFactory = windowFactory;
        }
        public static AppBuilder BuildAvaloniaApp()
            => AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
                .UsePlatformDetect()
                .LogToTrace()
                .UseReactiveUI();

        internal void ShowDialog()
        {
            BuildAvaloniaApp()
            .Start(AppMain, Array.Empty<string>());
        }

        private void AppMain(Application app, string[] args)
        {
            var window = windowFactory();
            window.Show();
            app.Run(window);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).